# Scrolling Header in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI report that has approximately 20 columns, which means that there has to be horizontal scrolling.  The columns fit into 2 categories, Current and YTD.  I have column headers, but want to group those with the overarching headers of Current (5 columns) and YTD (15 columns).  I have hit a roadblock of how to be able to accomplish this in Power BI and was wondering if anyone had any tips.  Creating static fields won't work since horizontal scrolling is necessary and the option of using a paid custom visualization isn't possible either.

I tried using a separate table that had the header name and a transparent URL image, but it I couldn't get the image to mimic a scrolling header like expected.  The static text box also just isn't working because of scrolling.  The size the text would have to be to allow for no scrolling is too small to be readable.

Updated to add a visual of what I'm looking for - the table in Power BI goes to Column M.  I want the headers of current and YTD to become "attached" to the column headers so that when I scroll left or right, the boxes will move with the appropriate column headers.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjX2i.png)

Comment: Can you update your question with a snip of the visual, and any other mock-ups that will help us visualize you need.